# What's the best way to integrate bitcoin API's into a wordpress site?

Tags: website-integration

I'm fairly new to coding, I understand the philosophy but I'm lacking practical application. Does anyone know any practical guides that will help me? I've completed most codeacademy courses.

Comment: @Fulgdenea I'm not looking to accept it. for example if I wanted to integrate the shapeshift API through wordpress, is that possible?

Comment: blockonomics has highly rated plugin on wordpress to accept bitcoin https://wordpress.org/plugins/blockonomics-bitcoin-payments/ .

Comment: What exactly is it you want this wordpress site to do with bitcoin APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Shapeshift plugin in your website. Build something like this. That's a good way to start with. You can see an example here http://radelcorp.in/shp

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the woocomerce plugin and btcpay?

The repository has instructions for deploying to wordpress.

https://github.com/btcpayserver/woocommerce-plugin/releases

[BTCPay Documentation for Installing WooCommerce plugin](https://docs.btcpayserver.org/integrations/woocommerce)

Answer (score -2):

I would refer you to the following for more details and i hope you will get answer there,

https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-accept-bitcoin-on-your-wordpress-site-6814

Comment: Could you summarize the contents of that link so that this answer will still be useful if that site goes down?

Comment: Link-only answers are considered very low quality. When posting a link in an answer, please check that you have covered some of the following questions in your post: *What good is this? Why do you suggest it? What's there? What will I find if I click this? Is there something I can take away without clicking it? Put it here, just in case.* See [Discussion on Link-only answers](http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/596/5406) for more information.